# DataTables: How to set page in preInit?

Tags: datatables

[The docs](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page()) say that I should be able to set the page via `DataTablesApiInstance.page(pageNumber)`, but I can't get it to work.

All the other API methods like `search` and `order` seem to work fine.

Here's my code:

```
$(document)
    .on('preInit.dt', (ev, settings) => {
        let tableId = ev.target.id;
        let tableState = _.get(['datatables', tableId], history.state) || {};

        let api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);

        if(tableState.hasOwnProperty('page')) {
            api.page(tableState.page); // <-- problem is here; page doesn't get set
        }

        if(tableState.hasOwnProperty('search')) {
            api.search(tableState.search);
        }

        if(tableState.hasOwnProperty('order')) {
            api.order(tableState.order);
        }

        const setState = (key, value) => {
            history.replaceState(_.set(['datatables', tableId, key], value, history.state), '');
        };

        api.on('page', ev => {
            let info = api.page.info();
            // console.log('page', tableId, info.page);
            setState('page', info.page);
        });

        api.on('order', ev => {
            let order = api.order();
            // console.log('order', tableId, order);
            setState('order', order);
        });

        api.on('search', ev => {
            setState('search', api.search());
        });
    });
```

The method is hit, but the page isn't set. Am I using the wrong API method? Is there another way to set the page before the data loads?

I'm using `datatables.net@1.10.12`.

---

If I defer the call to `init` instead of `preInit` then the correct page number is highlighted, but the data is still from the first page. If I add a 0ms delay on top of that (as below), it does work, but causes a 2nd data fetch + draw.

```
if(tableState.page) {
    api.on('init', ev => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            api.page(tableState.page).draw('page');
        }, 0);

    });
}
```

How can I set the page without incurring a 2nd ajax request?

Comment: You need to `draw()` the page as well -> `api.page(tableState.page).draw()`

Comment: @davidkonrad Thanks, but I tried that too. `.draw('page')` as well. Didn't work. I don't think it should be necessary on `preInit` though -- it draws right after.

Comment: Found this: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/86374/#Comment_86374 Looks like this issue was never resolved. I opened a ticket: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/39396/api-page-n-does-not-work-in-preinit-or-init

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`displayStart`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/displayStart) option to define the starting point for data display when using DataTables with pagination as [recommended by the author](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/86374/#Comment_86374) of jQuery DataTables.

It works correctly with table in server-side processing mode and only 1 Ajax request is performed.

```
var table = $("#example").DataTable({
     "processing": true,
     "serverSide": true,
     "ajax": "/test",
     "displayStart": 200     
 });
```

From the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/displayStart):

> Note that this parameter is the number of records (counting from `0`), rather than the page number, so if you have `10` records per page and want to start on the third page, it should be `20` rather than `2` or `3`.

Comment: The problem with that is that I don't want to copy this code to every DataTable I use on my site. I'm trying to do a catch-all, which is why I'm listening for the `preInit` event on `document`. If I could modify the settings from in there, I could make this work, but that's not possible is it?

Comment: @mpen, there could be other alternatives but before we dive deep into this, why you're not using [`stateSave`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave) instead which saves/restores pagination as well as other parameters such as search, order, etc.? You can use [`stateSaveCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveCallback) and [`stateLoadCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateLoadCallback) if you want to implement your own state-saving mechanism, no need for `preInit.dt` event handler.

Comment: Does `stateSave` only work on page reload/back? Or does it remember it forever? Because I only want the state to be restored when the user presses "back" which is why I started going down this road.

Comment: @mpen, See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40550946/getting-datatables-to-keep-its-state-when-the-user-clicks-the-back-button-witho) on the topic.

Comment: Ahah. That is exactly what I'm trying to do. I didn't see that before, but I can't say I'm fond of Dex's solution. Adding JS to every link to the page to clear the state is a pretty awful hack. My solution seems similar to [Aliester's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40718496/65387), except I didn't really want to alter the hash. I suppose I could do what I want with the state save+load callbacks. I will try that out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't (directly) answer the question of how to set the page in the preInit, but it solves my problem.

We can use the [`stateLoadCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateLoadCallback) to load the state (including page) from the history API instead of using `localStorage` as the default implementation does (which will remember the state even when navigating away and then back again).

```
$.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    stateSave: true,
    stateSaveCallback: (settings, data) => {
        let tableId = settings.nTable.id;
        if(!tableId) {
            // console.warn(`DataTable is missing an ID; cannot save its state`);
            return;
        }
        history.replaceState(_.set(['datatables', tableId], data, history.state), '');
    },
    stateLoadCallback: settings => {
        let tableId = settings.nTable.id;
        if(!tableId) {
            console.warn(`DataTable is missing an ID; cannot load its state`);
            return;
        }
        return _.get(['datatables', tableId], history.state) || null;
    }
});
```